# Spring form data binding - how to map a form property to a form attribute (when the form-property has a different name than the form-object)

Tags: java, data-binding, spring-mvc

```
public class MyForm {
  private String username;
  //getter...setter
}


@Controller
public class MyController {
  @RequestMapping("/handleForm")
  public String handleForm( MyForm form, Model model ){
    //do something
  }
}
```

If I submit a form to the above controller with a parameter 'username' all works great. 
I am currious though, just for user convenience I'd like to shorten the 'username' parameter to 'u' as in: http://mydomain.com?u=rocky (rather than http://mydomain.com?username=rocky).

But I'd rather not have MyForm.u, it's a little hard to read for future maintainability.

Can I map MyForm.username to the form parameter 'u'? Easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I map MyForm.username to the form
>   parameter 'u'? Easily?

You can (but not easily ;) ).

Similar question : [In Spring-mvc the attribute names in view have to always match the property names in model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380206/in-spring-mvc-the-attribute-names-in-view-have-to-always-match-the-property-names) (Like other users, I've also provided the answer under this question.)