# How do I map properties of a ModelAttribute?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I have a request mapped like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView createNewItem(@ModelAttribute PostRequest request)
```

and the PostRequest has some properties like e.g. `userName (getUserName()/setUserName())` but the client sends parameters like `user_name=foo` instead of `userName=foo`. Is there an annotation or custom mapping interceptor to do this without putting all these ugly `setUser_name()` methods?

As this happens very often (I have to implement an API where everything is using underscores) some effort in implementation is acceptable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customize parameter names when binding spring mvc command objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986593/how-to-customize-parameter-names-when-binding-spring-mvc-command-objects)

Comment: that's a good question. I faced it a couple of weeks ago. You can check if my solution works for you

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Spring's form tag library? http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib

The taglib (in combination with your controller) maps your ModelAttribute automatically. When doing the GET request for the form you create a new (maybe empty) object of your PostRequest and stick it into the model. After POSTing the form spring provides the ModelAttribute for you with the form values.

Schematic example:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/path", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String initForm(ModelMap model) {

        PostRequest pr = new PostRequest();
        model.addAttribute("command", pr);

        return "[viewname]";
    }

@RequestMapping(value="/path", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView postForm(
        @ModelAttribute("command") PostRequest postRequest) {

        // postRequest should now contain the form values
        logger.debug("username: " + postRequest.getUsername());

        return "[viewname]";
     }
```

jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<form:form method="post" enctype="utf8">
    Username: <form:input path="username" />
   <br/>
   <%-- ... --%>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form:form>
```

Comment: The Sping form tag library may not help in this case because the orignal poster speaks of an abitrary client which sends the parameters using underscores i.e. `user_name=foo` instead of `userName=foo`. In your case you need to have control over the Client (JSP).

Comment: Oh, ok - I didn't read it that way. And it's a little bit strange to have control over the ViewController but not the View itself!?

Comment: In my case I have to implement a REST API based on an existing specification as clients are already out in the wild. There is also no view as HTML but the response is automatically mapped depending on the accept header of the client.