# Spring 3 MVC Request parameter mapping. Two parameters from the same class while calling a handler in the controller

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-3, spring-annotations

I am trying to figure out how to pass two different parameters of the same class through the URL to a handler method in the controller. For example, given a "Foo" class with an "id" parameter(I am saying just one parameter to keep it simple, but think from a class with loads of them), the code of the controller looks as it follows:

```
@Controller(value = "customerCareRemoteService")
public class CustomerCareRemoteServiceImpl {

// Othe methods/requests

    @RequestMapping(value = "/" + "prueba" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String prueba(Foo pFoo1, Foo pFoo2) {
        //stupid and not interesting code
        String answer = "pFoo1.id is " + pFoo1.id + ". pFoo2.id is " + pFoo2.id.";
        System.out.println(answer);
        return answer;

    }

}
```

So, when I call this method, there is no way to differ between the two parameters:

```
http://myfakeurl/prueba?id=1&id=2
```

How should I deal with that? Is there any way to "prefix" the parameters? I have seen @RequestParam but it does not work for me, because it can not be used with my very own and beauty personal classes(or am I wrong?). Also I would like to avoid wrapper classes. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, with some help from a workmate, I have came to the next page that talks about that thema:

[Customizing Parameter Names When Binding Spring MVC Command Objects](http://java.dzone.com/articles/customizing-parameter-names)

Which leads to the next StackOverFlow question:

[How to customize parameter names when binding spring mvc command objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986593/how-to-customize-parameter-names-when-binding-spring-mvc-command-objects/9003314#9003314)

So it looks like there is no easy solution available like "using annotation X", but to create your own resolver, and use custom annotations (as a good newbie, I am still trying to understand it :-S).

Answer (score 1):

You should use @PathVariable to solve this problem.

Your mapping url would be like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/" + "prueba" + "/{id1}/{id2}" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

and the arguements in your function would be.

```
public @ResponseBody String prueba(@PathVariable int pFoo1, @PathVariable int pFoo2)
```

In this way you can get both the ID in your controller for further operation using them.

Hope this helped you.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but the point is that I wanted the URL parameter to fill an object attribute. I mean, I have said that the Foo object has one attribute, but it is only to keep the example simple. Actually I am trying to fill various attributes. But thanks :-)

Comment: In that case you should use @RequestAttribute that will bind all your attributes from your view to the model object.

Comment: Well...I think it works for primitive types, but not for attributes from classes(I mean, not for Foo.id ,  for example).

Comment: Ohh sorry I meant @ModelAttribute to use. Sorry for mistake. Please check this one. **@ModelAttribute** should do the work for you. :)

Comment: I am really sorry to be dull, but I have already read that a pair of times while looking on the web, but never found an explanation/example. The documentation from Spring keeps on saying that it is a way to bind the Controller with the model... But I don't understand how to convert parameters in the URL in an Object :-(

Comment: Why you need to convert them? They will be automatically gets bind to your @ModelAttribute object. I'm wondering why you need to convert them.

Comment: Well...The point is that, I need to be able to pass 2 attributes with the same name of same/different classes as a parameter in the URL. For example: http://fakeurl/prueba?id=1&id=2 . In that case, let's say the first "id" is an attribute from class Param1, and the second "id" is from class Param2. That is what I want to do, rename at least one of them to something,so they dont get mixed(by default, if you say "id=2", then both parameters will get the "2" value.