# Form submit in Spring MVC 3 - explanation

Tags: java, forms, spring, spring-mvc

I'm having problems understanding how does a form submit in Spring 3 MVC work.

What I want to do, is to create a controller which would take the user's name and display it to him. And somehow I have done it but I don't really understand how it works. So..

I have a form which looks like this:

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="person">
    <form:label path="firstName">First name</form:label>
    <form:input path="firstName" />
    <br />

    <form:label path="lastName">Last name</form:label>
    <form:input path="lastName" />
    <br />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form:form>
```

I also have a controller which looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showHelloPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String sayHello(Person person, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("person", person);
        return "home";
    }
}
```

To display a welcome message to a user I use the following code in the JSP page:

```
<c:if test="${not empty person.firstName and not empty person.lastName}">
    Hello ${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}!
</c:if>
```

And it works (I omit the XML configuration files because they are irrelevant to the problem).

I thought that the "modelAttribute" attribute in a form points to the bean variable which should be populated with inputs' values (as set in their "path" attributes). But looks, it works in a very different way. If I remove the line

```
model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
```

from "showHelloPage" method I get an (common) exception "Neither BindingResult nor...".

Also, on the beginning, the "sayHello" method looked like:

```
(...)
public String sayHello(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person, Model model) {
(...)
```

I mean, it had the "ModelAttribute" annotation. I added it, because in the tutorials I have read, it was always present. But after I removed it, everything worked well, as it did before.

**So my question is** - what is the use of the "ModelAttribute" anonnatation? Is it some way to omit a "modelAttribute" attribute in a form? And the second part, what is the way (maybe some annotation) to make a form automatically bind inputs' values to the proper bean's properties (which would be declared as a method parameter)? Without a need of adding an empty bean before sending a form (as I have to do it now).

Thanks for your replies (which aren't links to the Spring's documentation, because I have already read it).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The [`@ModelAttribute`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html) annotation in this case is used to identify an object that Spring should add as a model attribute. Model attributes are an abstraction from the `HttpServletRequest` attributes. Basically, they are objects identified by some key that will find their way into the `HttpServletRequest` attributes. You can do this by manually adding an attribute with `Model#addAttribute(String, Object)`, have a `@ModelAttribute` annotated method, or by annotating a method parameter with `@ModelAttribute`.

The thing you need to understand is how Spring resolves your handler method parameters and injects arguments. It uses the [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html%60) interface to do so. There are a number of implementing classes (see javadoc) and each has the responsibility to `resolveArgument()` by returning the argument that Spring will use to `invoke()` your handler method through reflection. Spring will only call the `resolveArgument()` method if the `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` `supportsParameter()` method returns `true` for the specific parameter.

The `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` implementation in question here is [`ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.html) which extends from [`ModelAttributeMethodProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.html) which states

> Resolves method arguments annotated with @ModelAttribute and handles
>   return values from methods annotated with @ModelAttribute.

Spring (3.2) will [register](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.html) this `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` and others

```
private List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> getDefaultArgumentResolvers() {
        List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver>();

    // Annotation-based argument resolution
    resolvers.add(new RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver(getBeanFactory(), false));
    resolvers.add(new RequestParamMapMethodArgumentResolver());
    resolvers.add(new PathVariableMethodArgumentResolver());
    resolvers.add(new ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor(false));
    resolvers.add(new RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor(getMessageConverters()));
    resolvers.add(new RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver(getMessageConverters()));
    resolvers.add(new RequestHeaderMethodArgumentResolver(getBeanFactory()));
    resolvers.add(new RequestHeaderMapMethodArgumentResolver());
    resolvers.add(new ServletCookieValueMethodArgumentResolver(getBeanFactory()));
    resolvers.add(new ExpressionValueMethodArgumentResolver(getBeanFactory()));

    // Type-based argument resolution
    resolvers.add(new ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver());
    resolvers.add(new ServletResponseMethodArgumentResolver());
    resolvers.add(new HttpEntityMethodProcessor(getMessageConverters()));
    resolvers.add(new RedirectAttributesMethodArgumentResolver());
    resolvers.add(new ModelMethodProcessor());
    resolvers.add(new MapMethodProcessor());
    resolvers.add(new ErrorsMethodArgumentResolver());
    resolvers.add(new SessionStatusMethodArgumentResolver());
    resolvers.add(new UriComponentsBuilderMethodArgumentResolver());

    // Custom arguments
    if (getCustomArgumentResolvers() != null) {
        resolvers.addAll(getCustomArgumentResolvers());
    }

    // Catch-all
    resolvers.add(new RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver(getBeanFactory(), true));
    resolvers.add(new ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor(true));

    return resolvers;
}
```

When Spring needs to invoke your handler method, it'll iterate through the parameter types and through the above list and use the first one that `supportsParameter()`.

Notice that two instances of `ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor` are added (one after a `//catch all` comment). The `ModelAttributeMethodProcessor` has a `annotationNotRequired` field which tells it if it should look for the `@ModelAttribute` or not. The first instance must look for `@ModelAttribute`, the second one doesn't. Spring does this so that you can register your own `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` instances, see the `// Custom arguments` comment.

---

Specifically

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String sayHello(Person person, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("person", person);
    return "home";
}
```

In this case, it doesn't matter if your `Person` parameter is annotated or not. A `ModelAttributeMethodProcessor` will resolve it and bind form fields, ie. request parameters, to the fields of the instance. You shouldn't even need to add it to the `model` as the `ModelAttributeMethodProcessor` class will handle that.

In your `showHelloPage()` method

```
model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
```

is needed with the `<form>` taglib. That's how it resolves its `input` fields.

---

> So my question is - what is the use of the "ModelAttribute"
>   anonnatation?

To automatically add the specified parameter (or method return value) to the model.

> Is it some way to omit a "modelAttribute" attribute in a form?

No, the `form` binding looks for an object in the `Model` and binds its fields to html `input` elements.

> And the second part, what is the way (maybe some annotation) to make a
>   form automatically bind inputs' values to the proper bean's properties
>   (which would be declared as a method parameter)? Without a need of adding 
>   an empty bean before sending a form (as I have to do it now).

A Spring `<form>` tag latches onto a model attribute object and uses its fields to create `input` and `label` elements. It doesn't matter how the object ended up in the model as long as it did. If it can't find a model attribute with the name (key) you specified, it throws exceptions, as you saw.

```
 <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="person">
```

The alternative to providing an empty bean is to create the html yourself. All Spring's `<form>` does is use the bean's field names to create an `input` element. So this

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="person">
    <form:label path="firstName">First name</form:label>
    <form:input path="firstName" />
```

Creates something like

```
<form method="post" action="[some action url]">
    <label for="firstName">First name<label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" value="[whatever value firstName field had]" />
    ...
```

Spring binds request parameters to instance fields using the `name` attribute.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, you explained me a lot. Just one more question about the "ModelAttribute" annotation - if I understand you correctly, this annotation used with a method parameter, is equivalent to "model.addAttribute(...)"?

Comment: @MichałTabor Try adding it as a method parameter. I'm unsure, if because the request doesn't have any request parameters that can be bound, it'll return `null`. Otherwise, the way you are doing is the correct way. These are known as Data Transfer Objects (or Spring form backing objects/command objects). The documentation should have more details.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thanks for your detailed explanation. Could you please elaborate a little bit more on the last part (the alternative to providing an empty bean)? In this case, since the `modelAttribute` isn't provided on the `form` tag, how the framework binds the `form` values to the command parameter on `@RequestMapping` method? Does it just try to use the bean present on the method?

Comment: Well, tried myself here. It worked as I've thought. Anyway, thanks again Sotirios. Your explanation should be on the Spring Docs!

Comment: @pasemes Note the difference between `<form>` and `<form:form>`. The former is the HTML element. The latter is the `form` tag of the `form` tag library that Spring provides. When the Spring `form` is rendered, it generates an HTML `form` with converted `<input>` names. With the HTML form, you would have to do it manually.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, I had understood that part as you explained in your answer. My question was just about how the framework would work when the `modelAttribute` is absent. How it knows which of the `@RequestMapping` method parameters is the command/form bean to be used?

Comment: @pasemes Oh, depends. It looks at the parameter type (from which it creates a name) or the name of the `@ModelAttribute`, it checks in the request attributes if such an attribute exists. If it doesn't, it creates and adds one. Then it uses the various properties and binds them to that attribute object.

Comment: @pas All this using the name of the `<input>` element.

Comment: Does the method signature 'public String sayHello(Person person)' also work in the scenario?

Comment: @emeraldjava Can you clarify? What do you intend it to do? Does the method have any annotations? I'd need more context.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Posted a question here, would appreciate any comments. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345306/spring-mvc-form-generating-new-model-object-instances

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis what is the best resource to learn spring mvc? I don't  find documentation competent enough.