# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'newCase' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have been reading through every page I can find about this error, and I just can't figure it out. What I'm doing is creating a form-backing object for a rather large form I have.

The purpose of this form (implemented as a Bootstrap modal) is to allow users to enter new entries into a database table. The form itself resides on the `/main` page. A user clicks on the add button, which makes the modal appear. They then enter all the fields, click on Save, and then an AJAX POST is made to `/add`, and that's where the controller should grab the data and populate a `SpecialClaimsCase` object with the data from the form.

The form is defined as:

`<form:form commandName="newCase" method="post">`

The controller method that renders the page the form resides on:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/main", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView view() {
    return new ModelAndView("application");
}
```

And the controller method that handles submission of the form:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void addRow(@ModelAttribute("newCase") SpecialClaimsCase newCase) {
    caseManager.addNewSpecialClaimsCase(newCase);
}
```

As soon as I go to load the page that the form is on, I get the following error:

> [8/1/14 14:32:17:866 CDT] 0000001f webapp        E
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E:
>   [Servlet Error]-[dispatcher]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither
>   BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'newCase'
>   available as request attribute    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:141)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:117)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
>     at
>   com.ibm._jsp._application._jspx_meth_form_input_0(_application.java:626)
>     at com.ibm._jsp._application._jspService(_application.java:191)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)  at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1214)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>     at
>   com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:205)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:926)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1023)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1384)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:266)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1225)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1012)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1214)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:926)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1023)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:895)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)   at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1659)

And here's the [fpaste link](http://fpaste.org/122635/14069223/) because the traceback is pretty unreadable here.

I'm pretty stuck here. The Spring documentation is pretty bare when it comes to this. I found a single sentence referencing this situation, and I followed what they said. Still nothing. So any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you feel that way, please post the handler that renders the page with the `form` in it.

Comment: You want the whole form? Because it's a good 250 lines long.

Comment: No, I don't want the form. I want the handler/controller/servlet/mapping that handles the request that will eventually result in displaying the form.

Comment: Thank you. Now read the answer in the duplicate, starting at _Your JSP contains..._. You need a model attribute named `newCase`.

Comment: Except as I stated, that does not work. I get the exact same error whether I add `modelAttribute="newCase"` to the JSP or not.

Comment: No. You miss the point. You need to add a model attribute to the request. You'd do this in the `view()` method, similarly to how the duplicate question adds a `customer` model attribute in the handler that renders the JSP. That's what the `form` uses to generate its `<input>` elements.

Comment: Let us know if there's still a problem.

Comment: So, I add a model attribute of "newCase" in the controller that handles `/main`. This seems weird, since I don't need the `newCase` until AFTER the user has entered all their info and clicked on save.

Comment: [Here's the Spring documentation about the `<form>` tag.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-formtag)

Comment: The tag uses the model attribute object as a template.

Comment: The last part of my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944627/form-submit-in-spring-mvc-3-explanation/18944736#18944736) also explains a bit how `<form>` works.