# What does InitBinder actually mean here?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

[Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/InitBinder.html) says this about InitBinder

> Annotation that identifies methods which initialize the WebDataBinder
>   which will be used for populating command and  form object arguments
>   of annotated handler methods.

What i got from this this method is used for initializing the WebDataBinder which is used to populate model object so that
it can be used further in handler method. But i am not sure what does `"... of annotated handler methods"` mean here?"

**Update :-** i believe it means after going thru  Sotirios Delimanolis answer

> InitBinder Annotation identifies methods which initialize the WebDataBinder
>   which will be used for model object that is further passes to handler method annotated with @RequestMapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A handler method is typically meant to distinguish [methods annotated with `@RequestMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-methods) within a `@Controller` or `@RequestMapping` annotated type (see [`RequestMappingHandlerMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html)).

For example,

```
@RequestMapping("/example")
public String setItemValue(@ModelAttribute Item item) {
    item.setValue(42);
    return "some-view";
}
```

An `@InitBinder` method could be used to help populate the `WebDataBinder` which will create the argument to be passed to the `setItemValue` handler method.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944627/form-submit-in-spring-mvc-3-explanation/18944736#18944736)'s some extra reading on `@ModelAttribute`. It is not necessarily required (just being explicit).

Comment: i believe you mean "@InitBinder method could be used to help populate the argument to be passed to the populateItem handler method." Correct? If yes Is it mandatory to annotate that particular argument with @ModelAttribute. I think no.

Comment: @user3198603 Edited with a link.

Comment: Thanks sotirios. Please see my update also. Your edition says the same stuff i mentioned in my edit. Thanks

Comment: @user3198603 Do you have another question or is something unclear?

Comment: One more quick thing, InitBinder method will be called before every call of handler method annotated with @RequestMapping. Correct ?

Comment: @user3198603 It will only be invoked if your handler method has appropriate model attributes/command object parameters.

Comment: what do yo mean by "appropriate model attributes/command object parameters" ? Can you explain it bit more?

Comment: @user3198603 If you have a handler method with a parameter annotation with `@ModelAttribute`, then an `@InitBinder` method will be invoked. If, however, your handler method doesn't have any such parameters, there's no point for the `@InitBinder` method to be invoked.

Comment: Another thing i found out that under initbinder method we generally register validator or customEditor . But Javadoc says we populate model object under it ?

Comment: @user3198603 I've reworded my answer. `@InitBinder` doesn't work on the model attribute. It works on the `WebDataBinder` which works on the model attribute.