# RestController method injection doesn't support singleton (Annotation Driven)

Tags: java, spring

The documentation says that the default bean scope for Spring is a singleton.

I couldn't find anything about method level injections bypassing this scope.

With this configuration

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ModuleProvider getModuleProvider() {
        return new ModuleProvider();
    }
}
```

Method One (which I expect for both outcomes):

```
@RestController
@Scope(value = "request")
@RequestMapping(value = "/application")
public class ApplicationController {
    @Autowired
    ModuleProvider moduleProvider;

    @RequestMapping
    public String showModules() {
        return moduleProvider.toString();
    }
}
```

Hitting it twice, the output is..

```
application.ModuleProvider@673f63cb
application.ModuleProvider@673f63cb
```

Method Two:

```
@RestController
@Scope(value = "request")
@RequestMapping(value = "/application")
public class ApplicationController {
    @Autowired   
    @RequestMapping
    public String showModules(ModuleProvider moduleProvider) {
        return moduleProvider.toString();
    }
}
```

Hitting it twice, the output is..

```
application.ModuleProvider@1cc4fbcb
application.ModuleProvider@57248dbf
```

Answer (score 4):

(You should actually see it three times in your second case.)

`@Autowired` is only processed when a bean is created and must have fields or methods injected.

When preparing your `ApplicationController` bean, Spring will find the `showModules` method annotated with `@Autowired` and invoke it by injecting the `ModuleProvider` bean from the `@Configuration` class.

After that, Spring is done with injections for `ApplicationController`.

When you subsequently send requests, Spring MVC takes over. This ignores `@Autowired` entirely. By default, arguments for `@RequestMapping` annotated methods in controller types are handled by `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`. In this case, an instance of type `ModelAttributeMethodProcessor` (or its `ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor` subclass) will generate the argument for the parameter of type `ModuleProvider`.

Each time it will create a new one. These instances are completely separate from the `ApplicationContext`. It's the same process as using a form parameter in your handler method.

Extra reading:

- [Form submit in Spring MVC 3 - explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944627/form-submit-in-spring-mvc-3-explanation/18944736#18944736)