# Is it possible to get hold of the value of the parameter from MethodParameter object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am extending the `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` to get hold of a parameter annotated by a custom annotation

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cases/{caseId}", params = "meta",
                method = PUT, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public String updateUIMetadata(
    @RequestBody
    @JsonData(schemaLocation = "schema/metadata_schema.json")
    final String metadataJson) {
}
```

I want to get hold of the value in my string `metadataJson` in my class, specifically in the `resolveArgument` method. I know it has a `MethodParameter` parameter, but is it possible to get hold of the actual value of the parameter which is passed along with the web request?

```
public class UpdateMetadataInterceptor implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {


@Override
public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
    return parameter.hasParameterAnnotation(JsonData.class);
}

@Override
public String resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter,
        ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest,
        WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Inside UpdateMetadata");
    // TODO something with metadataJson

}
}
```

Comment: The purpose of `resolveArgument` is to **provide** the value that will be bound to the parameter. Spring will call your `UpdateMetadataInterceptor#resolverArgument`, gets its return value, and invoke `updateUIMetadata` with it.

Comment: In this case, it doesn't make sense to annotate your parameter with both `@RequestBody` and `@JsonData`. Spring will use only one `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` (the one for `@RequestBody`) to produce an argument.

Comment: [Read this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944627/form-submit-in-spring-mvc-3-explanation/18944736#18944736)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So what I want to do is intercept the method `updateUIMetadata`, extract the value of the parameter and do something with it before the method is invoked. And I want to do it without using aop. I guess I should use `HandlerInterceptor` then. Or is there a better way that you might be aware of?

Comment: Spring MVC doesn't provide a way to intercept the arguments used to invoke your handler method. AOP seems appropriate.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I am still confused by your second comment. Can you please elaborate on it.

Comment: The arguments are resolved after the `HandlerInterceptor` is invoked so you don't get access to them. I think AOP is the only _simple_ way to do this at the moment.

Comment: But I have not used `HandlerInterceptor`. I am using `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver `

Comment: Neither of those can be used to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` is invoked only if Spring cannot resolve one or more of a method's arguments. In the above case, a simple String is annotated with `@RequestBody`. Hence, Spring will be able to resolve it from the web request. Thus `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` will never get invoked. In order to achieve what I wanted, I followed the following strategy

1. Remove the `@RequestBody` annotation and club it with the `@JsonData` annotation
2. Now, since Spring does not know how to resolve `metadataJson`, it will invoke `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`. Here, we need to implement the logic of `@RequestBody` to extract the string from the body of the web request. This I did as below:

   ```
   public class ValidateJsonSchema implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

   @Bean
   private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter() {
   return new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
   }
   private RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor requestResponseBodyMethodProcessor = null;

   @Override
   public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
   return parameter.hasParameterAnnotation(JsonData.class);
   }

   @Override
   public String resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter,
       ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest,
       WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
   String value = (String) getRequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor()
           .resolveArgument(parameter, mavContainer, webRequest, binderFactory);
   // do something with value
   return value;

   }

   private RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor getRequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor() {

   if (requestResponseBodyMethodProcessor == null) {
       List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = requestMappingHandlerAdapter().getMessageConverters();
       requestResponseBodyMethodProcessor = new RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor(messageConverters);
   }
   return requestResponseBodyMethodProcessor;
   }
   }
   ```

I used `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` to get the message converters and created a new instance of `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`. Then I called the `resolveArgument` method of the same instance which returned the object, which I then cast to String