# Passing Model Object as @RequestParameter to Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a JSP page that displays list of employees found.

```
 <c:forEach items="${employeeList}" var="employee">
            <div class="formRow" style="background-color: red">
                <div class="employeeResultColumnSmall">${employee.getEmpNo()}</div>
                <div class="employeeResultColumnRegular">${employee.getFirstName()}</div>
                <div class="employeeResultColumnRegular">${employee.getLastName()}</div>
                <div class="employeeResultColumnSmall">${employee.getGender()}</div>
                <div class="employeeResultColumnRegular">${employee.getDateOfBirth()}</div>
                <div class="employeeResultColumnRegular">${employee.getHireDate()}</div>
                <div class="employeeResultColumnRegular">${employee.getDept().getDeptName()}</div>
                <div class="employeeResultColumnSmall"><a href="/updateemployee?employee=${employee}">Update</a></div>
            </div>
 </c:forEach>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateemployee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView goUpdateEmployee(@RequestParam("employee") Employee employee){
    System.out.println(employee);
    return null;
}
```

I want to pass the employee bean to a controller whose update link is clicked. I tried doing it as shown above but not working.

Comment: Add your employee `Object` to `ModelAndView`....

Comment: @SaviNuclear I am unable to reach `goUpdateEmployee()` controller

Comment: From JSP you want go to Controller..??

Comment: @SaviNuclear yes so i can forward to update page with `Employee` object

Comment: You need a simple form submission, or consider using spring's form taglib, as mentioned in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944627/form-submit-in-spring-mvc-3-explanation)