# Spring MVC consume application/zip

Tags: java, spring-mvc, zip

I'm trying to add uploading zip files to my Spring REST API but I keep getting an error of not being able to consume `application/zip`

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/zip' not supported
```

Here is my function in my controller,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/zip", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/zip")
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadZip(@RequestBody InputStream inputStream) {
    try {
        uploadZip(inputStream)
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.warn("Error reading file", e);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error creating new job", e);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

What is causing this exception?

Comment: have you tried `application/octet-stream` instead?

Comment: Why do you think your app would/should be able to consume zipped content?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I want to be able to directly upload zips into my web app.

Comment: I get what you want. I'm asking why do you think what you have should work? What did you do to support that feature? (I'm basically asking you to show the research you did that lead you to believe that this would work.)

Comment: Also, please clarify what the `InputStream` argument should be. Should it be the raw request body content? Should it be a stream resulting from unzipping the content? Something else?

Comment: Instead of deleting your question, consider editing to clarify what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Given the `@RequestBody` annotation, Spring MVC will use a [`RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.html) to resolve an argument for invoking your method. This [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/handler/invocation/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) will attempt to find an [`HttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) which can parse `application/zip` body content and produce an instance of some subtype of `InputStream`.

There is no such built-in `HttpMessageConverter` implementation. You can write your own implementation and register it. The Spring MVC stack would pick it up and use it.

Alternatively, if you want just the raw body of the request as an `InputStream`, just remove the `@RequestBody` annotation. `InputStream` is one of the default [supported argument types](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments):

> `java.io.InputStream` / `java.io.Reader` for access to the request’s content. This value is the raw `InputStream`/`Reader` as exposed by the Servlet API.

Given the raw `InputStream`, you could wrap it in a `ZipInputStream` and do the unzipping yourself.

Another option is to write and register your own implementation of a `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` (that looks at a parameter annotation or the  actual type of the parameter) that unzips the content of the request into some object.

---

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944627/form-submit-in-spring-mvc-3-explanation) explains Spring MVC's `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` pattern in more detail.