# Binding query parameter to object property of command object used in Controller

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

Im using Command Object as input to the controller method named `search`. Im wondering how to bind query parameter named `$skip` to the `skip` variable in the Pagination object? Note the $ in the parameter name.

`public SearchResult search(Pagination pagination)`

which handles following url

```
http://localhost:8080/api/search?$top=5&$skip=2
```

QueryInfo looks like this:

public class Pagination {

```
private Integer skip;
private Integer top;

public Integer getSkip() {
    return skip;
}

public void setSkip(Integer skip) {
    this.skip = skip;
}

public Integer getTop() {
    return top;
}

public void setTop(Integer top) {
    this.top = top;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Pagination{" +
            "skip=" + skip +
            ", top=" + top +
            '}';
}
```

}

Also, is it possible to annotate the Command object with validation rules, such as length, required/optional, ++?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986593/how-to-customize-parameter-names-when-binding-spring-mvc-command-objects

Comment: Thanks, but I dont manage to compile that example...