# Spring's @RequestParam with Nested Objects / Rich Model Objects

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller, spring-4, http-request-parameters

Simple problem:

```
@Controller
class MyController {
  @RequestMapping(...)
  void test(MyModel m) {
    ...
  }
}

class MyModel {
  MyNestedModel a;
}

class MyNestedModel {
  @RequestParam("b[]")
  List<String> b;
}
```

This apperantly does not work, because `@RequestParam` only works with method parameters.

Is there a way to define the name of the request param within the model object?

---

Reason:

My `MyModel` and `MyNestedModel` classes is of course much bigger and I'd like to use for example `?a.b[]=TEST`.

---

Thanks for your help `:)`

---

**EDIT:** Looks like this is exactly my problem: [How to customize parameter names when binding spring mvc command objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986593/how-to-customize-parameter-names-when-binding-spring-mvc-command-objects)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customize parameter names when binding spring mvc command objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986593/how-to-customize-parameter-names-when-binding-spring-mvc-command-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring mvc can transfer the parameter for you. But the post data should be like:

```
{a.b[0] : "b1", a.b[1] : "b2"}
```

then you can get a list in m.a.b

Comment: No `POST`, no `JSON`. I need the data as `GET` parameters: `http;//localhost/test?a.b[]=TEST`

Comment: have you try http://localhost/test?a.b[0]=TEST. I think spring mvc will handler the parameter in the same way. And I know the post worked fine.

Comment: Strange, that works. Now I have `List<String> b` and tried the following requests: `?b=x&b=y` (works: [x, y]), `?b=x,y` (works: [x, y]), `?b[]=x` (fails), `?b[0]=x` (works: [x]), `?b[1]=y` (works: [null, y]). And when using `Set<String> b` I can only use `?b=x&b=y` and `?b=x,y`. `?b[0]=x` doesn't work with `Set`. Seems like there's no easy way to handle `?b[]=x`.