# Renaming a nested property of a Spring MVC model attribute

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-mvc-initbinders

I have the following form:

```
public class ChildcareWorkerAdvertisementForm extends AbstractForm<ChildcareWorkerAdvertisement> {

    @Valid
    @Override
    //Rename the property from "model" to "advertisement"?
    public ChildcareWorkerAdvertisement getModel() {
        return super.getModel();
    }

}
```

I would like to rename the property named `model` to something else, perhaps `advertisement` when binding occurs so that I can refer to it as  `advertisement` in the view (thymeleaf, etc...).

Is this possible using Spring MVC?

**edit 1**: Here is my application' `AbstractForm` class:

```
package com.bignibou.web.controller;

public class AbstractForm<T> {

    private T model;

    public T getModel() {
        return this.model;
    }

    public final void setModel(T model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
   ...
```

You can see it uses Generics which is very neat on the java part. However I would like to customize the name of the `model` property in the views hence my question.

Comment: How about this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986593/how-to-customize-parameter-names-when-binding-spring-mvc-command-objects

Comment: Can you post more details? Maybe sample code on github? What class is AbstractForm? Is it this one - http://spring-rich-c.sourceforge.net/1.1.0/apidocs/org/springframework/richclient/form/AbstractForm.html?

Comment: @Jigish: the AbstractForm is a custom class I have included in my edit: see edit above.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan: I did see this post but I was hoping Spring 4.1 provided a simpler way to achieve the property renaming on a controller-method basis...

Comment: have you tried just "add new" `advertisement` property to model e.g.:public ChildcareWorkerAdvertisement getAdvertismenet() {
        return super.getModel();
    } and similarly for setter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following in your controller

```
@Valid
@Override
@ModelAttribute("advertisement")
//Rename the property from "model" to "advertisement"?
public ChildcareWorkerAdvertisement getModel() {
    return super.getModel();
}
```