# Bean property 'xxxx is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Why am I getting this error even when everything seems fine

this is the code in my index.jsp code

```
<body>
        <center><h1>SERVICE</h1>
            <h2>Enter Service Details</h2>
        <form:form method="POST" commandName="servDetForm" action="AddService">
              <table style="appearance:dialog ">

                    <tr>
                        <td>Number</td>
                        <td><form:input path="xxx"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number</td>
                        <td><form:input path="xxx"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><form:button name="addService" value="Add Service">Add Service</form:button></td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
           </form:form>
            </center>
      </body>
```

where is my wrong?

Comment: If that is the model object, then that isn't the model object that is being used by the form. Post your controller as well.

Comment: controller code added

Comment: Do u realise u have a typo in ur model?
this.useraname = username;

Comment: It was when I was edditing the question on SO. Its been corrected

Comment: Well how about you show us the actual code, because the actual problem is likely to be a typo in your actual code that you have not reproduced in the question!

Comment: I agree with @StephenC copy paste the real code because this is pretty useless...

Comment: Add your model (not only the getters/setters) and the full code for the form (not only the fields). Also if this is pseudo code instead of your real code, then it it quite hard to help you.

Comment: I have re-edited my question. Showing the real codes I am working with

Comment: the `commandName` is referring to the `servDetForm` class while `getFRC_Number()` is in `ItasTb` class, sure it can't find them. Or I missed something?

Comment: Please post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a wrong instance to the view.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView indexView(){
    return new ModelAndView("index","servDetForm",new ServiceTb());
}
```

Also in your Bean need to use camelCase notation not snakecase. [camelcase vs snakecase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945172/binding-snake-case-request-parameters-to-a-spring-form) the explanation

Should be **ItasTb** entity

Change your JSP to:

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="servDetForm">
```

Comment: ItasTb is the name of the model where frc_Number is a field in this class

Comment: Then your question is wrong? the class with the attribute frc_Number is ItasTb

Comment: Please kindly recheck

Comment: your class name is "public class ItasTb" then in your controller you are doing a new ServiceTb(), and we dont know what do you have in your ServiceTb class. If you change to "new ItasTb()" in your controller will works

Comment: Please kindly recheck

Comment: Just cange your `commandName="servDetForm"` to `commandName="ItasTb"`, the form will be bound to this domain object. As far as I see, nothing is wrong the controllers

Comment: @Blaze check the update of my response, and change the form from commandName to modelAttribute

Comment: I am reading about, and i am afraid the problem is that you are using snake_case in place of camelCase for yours attributes, try to change yours attributes from frc_number to frcNumber

Comment: Is that the problem?

Comment: what about the database column name @Column(name = "FRC_Number")

Comment: Also this `action="AddService"` means this form will be forwarded to one of the controller methods with `@RequestMapping("\AddService")` annotated, while there is no such method to handle this request in your controller.

Comment: There is. It is actually a typo. In my controller @RequestMapping(value="AddService",method = RequestMethod.POST)

Comment: did you change the snake case to camel case?

Comment: Yes. I did that and even cleaned my project.

Comment: Wow. I re-naimed both the getters and setters and it worked. :)

Comment: My challenge now is to make it as a http post to the server