# Spring data. Sort using snake case parameter

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Could you tell me how to pass sort param to rest controller in snake_case format?

My entity class

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity extends BaseEntity{

  @Id
  private Long id;

  @Column
  private Long parentId;
}
```

Controller method

```
@GetMapping("list")
    List<MyEntity> getEntityList(
           @PageableDefault(sort = {"id"}, direction = Sort.Direction.DESC) Pageable pageable);
}
```

In request i want to use `?sort=parent_id`

I've created Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder and it builds correct snake_case json

But spring send me `Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property parent found for type MyEntity! Did you mean 'parentId'?` I think this is issue about parsing because spring cut everything after '_' symbol.

I've tried:

- @JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
- @Column(name = "parent_id") @JsonProperty("parent_id")
- @JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. For correct working with snake_case parameter values we need to create custom OncePerRequestFilter. This filter prepare params before passing to controller.

User nullptr used same way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945172/binding-snake-case-request-parameters-to-a-spring-form). By the way, using filter you can prepare any other params/values but this solution may produce mistakes. All requests will go through the filter.

```
@Configuration
public class SnakeCaseFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        final Map<String, String[]> formattedParams = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        //Convert values for each parameter
        for (String param : request.getParameterMap().keySet()) {
            String[] values = request.getParameterValues(param);

            String formattedParam = CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL, param);

        formattedParams.put(formattedParam, values);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(new CustomResponseWrapper(request, formattedParams), response);

    }


    /**
     * Wrapper return new formatted parameters
     */
     class CustomResponseWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

        /**
         * Constructs a request object wrapping the given request.
         *
         * @param request the {@link HttpServletRequest} to be wrapped.
         * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the request is null
         */

        private Map<String, String[]> params;

        public CustomResponseWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, Map<String, String[]> params) {
            super(request);
            this.params = params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap() {
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
            return params.get(name);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to change the case of the value, but did it for the parameter name :) How is this supposed to work?

Comment: @Vijit In my case I needed to cast into snake case key, not value. By default spring use camelCase keys

I needed ?sort=parent_id instead of ?sort=parentId

The code in answer is fix that

Comment: Oh.. Obviously I missed the point )