# How to map multiple parameter names to POJO when binding spring mvc command objects

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

My question is actually a spin-off of this question [as seen here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986593/how-to-customize-parameter-names-when-binding-spring-mvc-command-objects) so it might help to check that thread before proceeding.

In my Spring Boot project, I have two entities `Sender` and `Recipient` which represent a `Customer` and pretty much have the same fields, so I make them extend the base class `Customer`;

***Customer* base class;**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Customer extends AuditableEntity {

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @Transient
    private CustomerRole role;

    public Customer(CustomerRole role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    //other fields & corresponding getters and setters
}
```

***Sender* domain object;**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "senders")
public class Sender extends Customer {

    public Sender(){
        super.setRole(CustomerRole.SENDER);
    }
}
```

***Recipient* domain object;**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "recipients")
public class Recipient extends Customer {

    public Recipient(){
        super.setRole(CustomerRole.RECIPIENT);
    }
}
```

NOTE - `Sender` and `Recipient` are exactly alike except for their roles. These can be easily stored in a single **customers** Table by making the `Customer` base class an entity itself, but I intentionally separate the entities this way because I have an obligation to persist each customer type in separate database tables.

Now I have one form in a view that collects details of both `Sender` & `Recipient`, so for example to collect the firstname, I had to name the form fields differently as follows;

***Sender section of the form;***

```
<input type="text" id="senderFirstname" name="senderFirstname" value="$!sender.firstname">
```

***Recipient section of the form;***

```
<input type="text" id="recipientFirstname" name="recipientFirstname" value="$!recipient.firstname">
```

But the fields available for a customer are so many that I'm looking for a way to map them to a pojo by means of an annotation as asked in [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986593/how-to-customize-parameter-names-when-binding-spring-mvc-command-objects). However, the solutions provided [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986593/how-to-customize-parameter-names-when-binding-spring-mvc-command-objects) would mean that I have to create separate proxies for both domain objects and annotate the fields accordingly e.g

```
public class SenderProxy {

    @ParamName("senderFirstname")
    private String firstname;

    @ParamName("senderLastname")
    private String lastname;
    //...
}

public class RecipientProxy {

    @ParamName("recipientFirstname")
    private String firstname;

    @ParamName("recipientLastname")
    private String lastname;
    //...
}
```

So I got very curious and was wondering, is there a way to map this Proxies to more than one @ParamName such that the base class for example can just be annotated as follows?;

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Customer extends AuditableEntity {

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    @ParamNames({"senderFirstname", "recipientFirstname"})
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    @ParamNames({"senderLastname", "recipientLastname"})
    private String lastname;

    @Transient
    private CustomerRole role;

    public Customer(CustomerRole role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    //other fields & corresponding getters and setters
}
```

And then perhaps find a way to select value of fields based on annotation??

Comment: There is no `@ParamName` you can use in your entity so not sure what you are using.

Comment: Sure... but that's why I pointed out to check the thread that I referenced by those links so you can have an idea of where @ParamName annotation came from

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion from Zhang Jie [like ExtendedBeanInfo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18012)

so i do it this way

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Alias {
    String[] value();
}

public class AliasedBeanInfoFactory implements BeanInfoFactory, Ordered {
    @Override
    public BeanInfo getBeanInfo(Class<?> beanClass) throws IntrospectionException {
        return supports(beanClass) ? new AliasedBeanInfo(Introspector.getBeanInfo(beanClass)) : null;
    }

    private boolean supports(Class<?> beanClass) {
        Class<?> targetClass = beanClass;
        do {
            Field[] fields = targetClass.getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field : fields) {
                if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Alias.class)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            targetClass = targetClass.getSuperclass();

        } while (targetClass != null && targetClass != Object.class);

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 100;
    }
}

public class AliasedBeanInfo implements BeanInfo {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AliasedBeanInfo.class);

    private final BeanInfo delegate;

    private final Set<PropertyDescriptor> propertyDescriptors = new TreeSet<>(new PropertyDescriptorComparator());

    AliasedBeanInfo(BeanInfo delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.propertyDescriptors.addAll(Arrays.asList(delegate.getPropertyDescriptors()));

        Class<?> beanClass = delegate.getBeanDescriptor().getBeanClass();
        for (Field field : findAliasedFields(beanClass)) {
            Optional<PropertyDescriptor> optional = findExistingPropertyDescriptor(field.getName(), field.getType());
            if (!optional.isPresent()) {
                LOGGER.warn("there is no PropertyDescriptor for field[{}]", field);
                continue;
            }
            Alias alias = field.getAnnotation(Alias.class);
            addAliasPropertyDescriptor(alias.value(), optional.get());
        }
    }

    private List<Field> findAliasedFields(Class<?> beanClass) {
        List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
        ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(beanClass,
                fields::add,
                field -> field.isAnnotationPresent(Alias.class));
        return fields;
    }

    private Optional<PropertyDescriptor> findExistingPropertyDescriptor(String propertyName, Class<?> propertyType) {
        return propertyDescriptors
                .stream()
                .filter(pd -> pd.getName().equals(propertyName) && pd.getPropertyType().equals(propertyType))
                .findAny();
    }

    private void addAliasPropertyDescriptor(String[] values, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor) {
        for (String value : values) {
            if (!value.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    this.propertyDescriptors.add(new PropertyDescriptor(
                            value, propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod(), propertyDescriptor.getWriteMethod()));
                } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
                    LOGGER.error("add field[{}] alias[{}] property descriptor error", propertyDescriptor.getName(),
                            value, e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public BeanDescriptor getBeanDescriptor() {
        return this.delegate.getBeanDescriptor();
    }

    @Override
    public EventSetDescriptor[] getEventSetDescriptors() {
        return this.delegate.getEventSetDescriptors();
    }

    @Override
    public int getDefaultEventIndex() {
        return this.delegate.getDefaultEventIndex();
    }

    @Override
    public PropertyDescriptor[] getPropertyDescriptors() {
        return this.propertyDescriptors.toArray(new PropertyDescriptor[0]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getDefaultPropertyIndex() {
        return this.delegate.getDefaultPropertyIndex();
    }

    @Override
    public MethodDescriptor[] getMethodDescriptors() {
        return this.delegate.getMethodDescriptors();
    }

    @Override
    public BeanInfo[] getAdditionalBeanInfo() {
        return this.delegate.getAdditionalBeanInfo();
    }

    @Override
    public Image getIcon(int iconKind) {
        return this.delegate.getIcon(iconKind);
    }

    static class PropertyDescriptorComparator implements Comparator<PropertyDescriptor> {

        @Override
        public int compare(PropertyDescriptor desc1, PropertyDescriptor desc2) {
            String left = desc1.getName();
            String right = desc2.getName();
            for (int i = 0; i < left.length(); i++) {
                if (right.length() == i) {
                    return 1;
                }
                int result = left.getBytes()[i] - right.getBytes()[i];
                if (result != 0) {
                    return result;
                }
            }
            return left.length() - right.length();
        }
    }
}
```