# @ModelAttribute: map fields to parameters

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, get

I should create a Get service (using spring boot) with a lot of parameters.
 I want to bind these parameters directly to my bean with `@ModelAttribute`.
**The problem**: there is some differences between fields in the bean and the Get parameters.
**Example**:

- url: http://localhost:8080/api/v1?form_id=123&idPart=353
- bean: 
     `private String formId; private String idPart;`

So for idPart there is no problem, but for formId the value is not mapped.
 Is there any Spring annotation that map the `formId` field to `form_id` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any build in  annotation for that. The easiest way would be to add setter in your been if you can do that

```
public void setForm_id(String formId) {
    this.formId = formId;
}
```

But you probably can look at other options https://stackoverflow.com/a/16520399/1032167