# Spring boot REST MVC map request parameter with different field name to object

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-rest, spring-web, http-request-parameters

Assume that I have want to capture a bunch of request parameters as one object like this:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public List<Item> filterItems(@Valid Filter filter){}
```

and the `Filter` class looks like this:

```
class Filter {
        public String status;
        public String start;
        public String end;
    }
```

Now in the API the request parameter name is `state` instead of `status` like this `?state=A&start=1&end=2`. How do I make these request parameters to map to my Filter object without having to rename `status`? I know if I have `@RequestParam("state") String status` it would work but I want it to be part of the request object.

I tried adding `@JsonProperty('state')` on the field but it didn't work.

Comment: Why you don't post the field in the request body, this will work adding @RequestBody also `JsonProperty` only will work on json if you post the entire object in the request.

Comment: I cannot change the API so it has to be in the request parameters. So there is no way to map it to another name other than have it as individual `@RequestParam` argument?

Comment: So you cannot change Filter class and the calling code which is passing queryparam as state instead of status?

Comment: Also you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986593/how-to-customize-parameter-names-when-binding-spring-mvc-command-objects, focus on the jkee's answer