# How to set param name for the binded POJO in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc, parameters

I have POJO class that represents list of request params.

Currently it uses field names, but I need to set them to kebab-case naming.
For example: `List<Product> productIds = new ArrayList<>()` should accept request param `product-ids` instead of `productIds`.

Using directly `@RequestParam` I can do `@RequestParam(name="product-ids")`, but I need it using binded POJO.

`@JsonProperty` or `@JsonNaming(KebabCaseStrategy.class)` don't work on that fields, I think because it's not a serialiazable object, but just a request param container.

Examples in [How to customize parameter names when binding Spring MVC command objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986593/how-to-customize-parameter-names-when-binding-spring-mvc-command-objects)
dont work for me.

Exception:

```
|  paramNameProcessor (field private org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter com.example.jpastudy.config.ParamNameProcessor.requestMappingHandlerAdapter)
↑     ↓
|  requestMappingHandlerAdapter defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]
└─────┘
```

How could I resolve that?

Comment: So you're using it like this? `void request(BoundedPojo boundedPojo)`

Comment: Yes, I pass Pojo to controller method argument @IdanElhalwani

Comment: From what I remember it uses the name of the setter to determine this. Is switching to RequestBody an option for you? Alternatively look here: [How to customize parameter names when binding Spring MVC command objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986593/how-to-customize-parameter-names-when-binding-spring-mvc-command-objects)

Comment: No I need request param, not json body.
I tried that examples from link, all of them are not valid, not working... There is mistakes with beans configuration, etc.

Comment: @IdanElhalwani any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem adding property:

`spring.main.allow-circular-references=true`

BUT I am not sure that it's a correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

I used this as a workaround.

```
import java.beans.ConstructorProperties;

public class RequestParamsDto {

    private List<Product> productIds;

    @ConstructorProperties("product-ids")
    public RequestParamsDto(List<Product> productIds) {
        this.productIds = productIds;
    }

    public List<Product> getProductIds() {
        return this.productIds;
    }

    public void setProductIds(List<Product> productIds) {
        this.productIds = productIds;
    }
}
```